# OpenMDAO cache_linear_solution not updating initial guess

Tags: python, openmdao

I want to save time on expensive linear solves for my optimization by using the previous linear solutions as initial guesses for the subsequent iteration in an optimization. I'm looking through OpenMDAO's example for the `cache_linear_solution` feature which seems to have been developed for this purpose ([here](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/linear_restart.html?highlight=cache)) and code shown below:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.sparse.linalg import gmres

import openmdao.api as om


class QuadraticComp(om.ImplicitComponent):
    """
    A Simple Implicit Component representing a Quadratic Equation.

    R(a, b, c, x) = ax^2 + bx + c

    Solution via Quadratic Formula:
    x = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
    """

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('a', val=1.)
        self.add_input('b', val=1.)
        self.add_input('c', val=1.)
        self.add_output('states', val=[0,0])

        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*')

    def apply_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs, residuals):
        a = inputs['a']
        b = inputs['b']
        c = inputs['c']
        x = outputs['states'][0]
        y = outputs['states'][1]

        residuals['states'][0] = a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
        residuals['states'][1] = a * y + b

    def solve_nonlinear(self, inputs, outputs):
        a = inputs['a']
        b = inputs['b']
        c = inputs['c']
        outputs['states'][0] = (-b + (b ** 2 - 4 * a * c) ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
        outputs['states'][1] = -b/a

    def linearize(self, inputs, outputs, partials):
        a = inputs['a'][0]
        b = inputs['b'][0]
        c = inputs['c'][0]
        x = outputs['states'][0]
        y = outputs['states'][1]

        partials['states', 'a'] = [[x**2],[y]]
        partials['states', 'b'] = [[x],[1]]
        partials['states', 'c'] = [[1.0],[0]]
        partials['states', 'states'] = [[2*a*x+b, 0],[0, a]]

        self.state_jac = np.array([[2*a*x+b, 0],[0, a]])

    def solve_linear(self, d_outputs, d_residuals, mode):

        if mode == 'fwd':
            print("incoming initial guess", d_outputs['states'])
            if LooseVersion(scipy.__version__) < LooseVersion("1.1"):
                d_outputs['states'] = gmres(self.state_jac, d_residuals['states'], x0=d_outputs['states'])[0]
            else:
                d_outputs['states'] = gmres(self.state_jac, d_residuals['states'], x0=d_outputs['states'], atol='legacy')[0]
        elif mode == 'rev':
            if LooseVersion(scipy.__version__) < LooseVersion("1.1"):
                d_residuals['states'] = gmres(self.state_jac, d_outputs['states'], x0=d_residuals['states'])[0]
            else:
                d_residuals['states'] = gmres(self.state_jac, d_outputs['states'], x0=d_residuals['states'], atol='legacy')[0]

p = om.Problem()
indeps = p.model.add_subsystem('indeps', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes_outputs=['a', 'b', 'c'])
indeps.add_output('a', 1.)
indeps.add_output('b', 4.)
indeps.add_output('c', 1.)
p.model.add_subsystem('quad', QuadraticComp(), promotes_inputs=['a', 'b', 'c'], promotes_outputs=['states'])

p.model.add_design_var('a', cache_linear_solution=True)
p.model.add_constraint('states', upper=10)


p.setup(mode='fwd')
p.run_model()

print(p['states'])

derivs = p.compute_totals(of=['states'], wrt=['a'])
print(derivs['states', 'a'])

p['a'] = 4
derivs = p.compute_totals(of=['states'], wrt=['a'])
print(derivs['states', 'a'])
```

The above code gives the following print out:

```
[-0.26794919 -4.        ]
incoming initial guess [0. 0.]
[[-0.02072594]
 [ 4.        ]]
incoming initial guess [0. 0.]
[[-0.02072594]
 [ 4.        ]]
```

From the print out of this example it doesn't look like the initial guess for the linear guess is actually being updated. Am I missing something? I've also tried running the code with the `cache_linear_solution` set to `False` and the result seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the caching of linear solutions only happens when the total derivatives are computed during the run of a driver, so if you want to check to make sure it's happening during your optimization (in the `run_driver` call), change

```
derivs = p.compute_totals(of=['states'], wrt=['a'])
```

to

```
derivs = p.driver._compute_totals(of=['states'], wrt=['a'], global_names=False)
```

When I do that with your code, I get the following output:

```
[-0.26794919 -4.        ]
incoming initial guess [0. 0.]
[[-0.02072594]
 [ 4.        ]]
incoming initial guess [-0.02072594  4.        ]
[[-0.02072594]
 [ 4.        ]]
```

Note that the `global_names=False` arg is only needed if you use promoted names for your `of` and `wrt` variables.

I will update our example code to reflect the correct way to do this.